# when i substring emoji its crashing. Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

This code works fine when I enter a simple string like hello @amit. but it throws crash when I use emoji with @df. crash in the substring. when I get the text by substring in the simple text it works fine but with emoji its throws crash.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text:String) -> Bool {
    //var mentionStartPosition : Int = 0
    //var isContainMention : Bool = false

    //WHEN USER TYPE TEXT COMPLETE TEXT ADD NEW CHAR IN COMPLETETEXT
    let completeText = textView.text + text
    // CHECK char FOR IF USER PRESS BACKSPACE OR NOT
    //ENNCODE THE CURRENT TEXT
    if let char = text.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        //GET THE VALUE UNICODE
        let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")
        //BACKSPACE PRESSED
        if (isBackSpace == -92) {
            if let selectedRange = textView.selectedTextRange {
                let cursorPosition = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.end)
                if mentionStartPosition < cursorPosition {

                    let textBetween = completeText.substring(Range(mentionStartPosition ... cursorPosition))
                    if textBetween.contains("@") {
                        isContainMention = true
                    } else {
                        isContainMention = false
                    }
                } else {
                    isContainMention = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    if text.contains("@") {
        
            isContainMention = true
            searchText += text
        return true
    } else if isContainMention {

        if let char = text.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")
            if (isBackSpace == -92) {
                if searchText.count > 0 {
                    searchText.removeLast()
                    if searchText.isEmpty {
                        isContainMention = false
                        searchText = ""
                    }

                } else {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        if let selectedRange = textView.selectedTextRange {
            
            let whitespace = NSCharacterSet.whitespaces
            let range = text.rangeOfCharacter(from: whitespace, options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
            let cursorPosition = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)
            let textBetween = completeText.substring(Range(mentionStartPosition ... cursorPosition))
            if textBetween.contains("@") {
                let from = completeText.substring(from: cursorPosition)
                if cursorPosition != 1 {
                    let beforeText = completeText.substring(from: cursorPosition - 1)
                    if beforeText == "@" {
                        isContainMention = false
                        searchText = ""
                        return true
                    }
                }
                searchText += from
            }
            else {
                 isContainMention = false
                 searchText = ""
            }
        }
        return true
    } 
}




func substring(_ r: Range<Int>) -> String {
    let fromIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: r.lowerBound)
    let toIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: r.upperBound - 1)
    let indexRange = Range<String.Index>(uncheckedBounds: (lower: fromIndex, upper:toIndex))
    return String(self[indexRange])
}
```

Comment: Which line of code crashes? Is there anything printed in the console?

Comment: The offset method returns the utf16 distance. You need to construct a NSRange and create a string range from that.

Comment: @aheze crash is on substring method    let textBetween = completeText.substring(Range(mentionStartPosition ... cursorPosition)) suppose i enter @g when I fetch textbetween from @g then on g it gets crash due to Unicode. It works perfectly for normal strings like gettextafter@abc.